# Getting RGB value from under mouse cursor

Tags: java, swing, awt, cursor-position, mixing

I am trying to build a program that detects the color that is under the mouse cursor and then displays the color and RGB values in a window on the screen. I am VERY new to Java so do not know much of anything. I have two codes I have worked on, with help from a friend, The first one gets the RGB values of a specific coordinate of a buffered image, and the other takes user defined RGB values and shows a pane with the color in it. My question is "how do I get the program to detect the color under the mouse cursor no matter what it is scrolling over?

```
public class Buffered_Image 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/user/Pictures/Hornet.jpg"));
    Color c = new Color(bi.getRGB(50,40));
    int red=c.getRed();
    int green=c.getGreen();
    int blue=c.getBlue();

    System.out.print("Red " + red + " Green " + green+ " Blue" + blue + "\n" );
}
}




public class RGB_Pane 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame F = new JFrame("RGB");
    Panel Pan = new Panel();
    F.getContentPane().add(Pan);
    F.pack();
    F.setVisible(true);
    F.setSize(300, 300);
}
}

class Panel extends JPanel
{
public Panel()
{ 
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    int Red = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for RED"));
    int Green = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for Green"));
    int Blue = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for BLUE"));
    Color Defined_Color = new Color(Red,Green,Blue);
    setBackground(Defined_Color);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the color within your context of you application or the whole system?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer- When the programs starts running, there needs to be a pane that pops up, and in the pane I need to be able to see the RGB value and an example of the color that is directly under the cursor. the pane should be able to show this no matter what is on the screen or what other programs are running.

Comment: The [Robot class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) has `getPixelColor(...)`. I'd look into trying to use that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Aww, and there I was going to go grab a screen shoot of 1x1 at the current mouse position :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Hovercraft has pointed out.

Start by looking at [`Robot#getPixelColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#getPixelColor%28int,%20int%29).

You will need to know where the mouse cursor is, while there's no "easy" way to track the cursor, you can get it's current location using [`MouseInfo#getPointerInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html#getPointerInfo%28%29)

**UPDATED with example**

This is little example of the concept.  This works based on the moition of the mouse cursor.  A possible enhancement would be to also notify the monitor listener when the color changes under the cursor as well...

```
public class WhatsMyColor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new WhatsMyColor();
    }

    public WhatsMyColor() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new MouseColorPane());
                    frame.setSize(400, 200);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public class MouseColorPane extends JPanel implements MouseMonitorListener {

        private Robot robot;

        private JLabel label;

        public MouseColorPane() throws AWTException {

            label = new JLabel();

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);

            robot = new Robot();
            PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            updateColor(pi.getLocation());
            MouseMonitor monitor = new MouseMonitor();
            monitor.setMouseMonitorListener(this);
            monitor.start();

        }

        protected void updateColor(Point p) {

            Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y);
            setBackground(pixelColor);

            label.setText(p.x + "x" + p.y + " = " + pixelColor);

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePositionChanged(final Point p) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateColor(p);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    public interface MouseMonitorListener {

        public void mousePositionChanged(Point p);
    }

    public static class MouseMonitor extends Thread {

        private Point lastPoint;
        private MouseMonitorListener listener;

        public MouseMonitor() {
            setDaemon(true);
            setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
        }

        public void setMouseMonitorListener(MouseMonitorListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public MouseMonitorListener getMouseMonitorListener() {
            return listener;
        }

        protected Point getMouseCursorPoint() {
            PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            return pi.getLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lastPoint = getMouseCursorPoint();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                Point currentPoint = getMouseCursorPoint();
                if (!currentPoint.equals(lastPoint)) {
                    lastPoint = currentPoint;
                    MouseMonitorListener listener = getMouseMonitorListener();
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.mousePositionChanged((Point) lastPoint.clone());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Shhh, I did a test example and it works really well ;)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Be careful of what you ask for ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hey guys, I am not sure if I am allowed to do this, but I "Answered" my own question because I didnt know of any other way to get my new code into this question because the comment block is too small. please check it out and let me know if you can help me anymore on this project. Thank You