# rgb values under the mouse

Tags: java, rgb

How can i get my program to read the rgb values under my mouse while i hover over the screen and have a Jframe display the color itself. the rgb values. and possibly the name of the color

So as my title displays i need a pixel color detector

here is what i have so far it opens the jframe but does nothing else

```
package project;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Project {
    private static int EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

//timer = new Timer(1000,this); 
JFrame frame= new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//JLabel lable = new JLabel(); 
//JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(lable);
//frame.getContentPane().add(jsp); 
frame. setSize(1000, 700);
frame.setVisible(true);

while(true) {


       PointerInfo cursorLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point position = cursorLocation.getLocation(); 
        int x = (int)position.getX(); 
        int y = (int)position.getY();

Robot bob = new Robot();

Color pixelColor = bob.getPixelColor(x, y);
int colorRed = pixelColor.getRed(); 
int colorGreen = pixelColor.getGreen(); 
int colorBlue = pixelColor.getBlue();
//System.out.print("Red " + colorRed + " Green " + colorGreen + " Blue " + colorBlue + "\n" );

 frame.setName("Red " + colorRed + " Green " + colorGreen + " Blue " + colorBlue );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061122/getting-rgb-value-from-under-mouse-cursor/13061320#13061320) for some ideas

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers from previous if you want to get help in the future.

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop to perform UI operations where it might block the EDT

Comment: thank you all sorry was busy for a few ill try the suggestions and let yall know soon :)

Comment: Mad- what do you suggest i replace while with ?

Comment: @user2950612, did you look at the link given to you in the first comment??? Why do you think we should keep giving you advice? You still haven't accepted/replied to the answer you got in your last posting.

Comment: i have looked i dont understand what to put in place of that.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to use while(true). Somewhere in there you should probably have a Thread.sleep(...). I would definitely check out MadProgrammer's solution.

Anyway the problem with your posted code is:

```
frame.setName("...");
```

You want:

```
frame.setTitle("...");
```

Comment: Thank you but how do i get the rgb values to show inside the box not as the name of the box ?

Comment: @user2950612, start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics of creating a GUI in Swing. Maybe the section on `How to Use Labels` would be a good place to start.