# Java - Set half of a JFrame to a specific color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, setbackground

Im trying to set the horizontal half of the JFrame to display the color that the cursor is on.
This is what I got so far.

```
enter code here
package finalproject;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;
public class FinalProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel rgbLabel = new JLabel();
        rgbLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.NORTH);
        rgbLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(rgbLabel);
        rgbLabel.setAlignmentX(50);
        rgbLabel.setAlignmentY(10);
        rgbLabel.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(650, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle(display.TITLE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(display.WIDTH, display.HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (true){
            PointerInfo cursorLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point position = cursorLocation.getLocation(); 
            int x = (int)position.getX(); 
            int y = (int)position.getY();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
            int colorRed = pixelColor.getRed(); 
            int colorGreen = pixelColor.getGreen(); 
            int colorBlue = pixelColor.getBlue();
            rgbLabel.setText("Red: " + colorRed + " Green: " + colorGreen + " Blue: "     + colorBlue + "\n" );

            }
        }
    public static class display {
        public static final int WIDTH = 250;
        public static final int HEIGHT = 135;
        public static final String TITLE = "Colorblind Assistant";
    }
}
```

I know that putting

```
frame.getContantPane().setBackground(pixelColor);
```

under the while loop will change the whole frame to the color, but I only need the bottom half of the frame to be that color.

Some help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Draw a colored box on half the frame in the appropriate `paint` method (e.g. extend the JFrame). The background color fills the entire graphics region during a "clear" and is done before children render on top of it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118737/how-to-draw-in-jpanel-swing-graphics-java

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061122/getting-rgb-value-from-under-mouse-cursor/13061320#13061320) for some help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a MouseListener, not a `while (true)` that will tie up the Swing event thread.
- Get all that code out of the main method and into a proper class. The main method should do nothing other than set your program in motion.
- Have your JFrame hold two JPanels in a GridLayout, and in the background of one of the JPanels be set by the MouseListener.