# Mouse Coordinate Finder GUI won't run correctly

Tags: java, jframe, mouse

I wanted to make a program with JFrame that would allow you to start and stop a JLabel from being updated with the most recent coordinate of the mouse cursor. I can't figure out what I have done wrong. Please help and be respectful. I'm new at Java so I can't help what dumb mistakes I've made.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PrintPos extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
    public JButton startBtn;
    public JButton stopBtn;
    public static JLabel posLabelX;
    public static JLabel posLabelY;
    static boolean started=false;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new PrintPos();
    }


    PrintPos() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        startBtn = new JButton("Start");
        stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
        posLabelY = new JLabel("X:");
        posLabelX = new JLabel("Y:");

        add(startBtn);
        add(stopBtn);
        add(posLabelX);
        add(posLabelY);

        setSize(200,150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
          {
              started = true;
              while(started) {
                    PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                    Point p = inf.getLocation();
                    posLabelX.setText(String.valueOf(p.x));
                    posLabelY.setText(String.valueOf(p.y));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        return;
                    }
                    }
          }
        });

        stopBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              started = false;
          }
        });
    }

        public static void getInfo() {
            while(started) {
                PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point p = inf.getLocation();
                posLabelX.setText(String.valueOf(p.x));
                posLabelY.setText(String.valueOf(p.y));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: You're blocking the event dispatching thread, have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for some ideas for solutions and for a runnable example, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061122/getting-rgb-value-from-under-mouse-cursor/13061320#13061320)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're blocking the event dispatching thread.  The EDT is responsible for processing events and paint requests and responding to user input.  While your `while` is running in the `ActionListener`, the EDT is unable to process any new events and your program will "hang"

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for some ideas for solutions.

And for a runnable example, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061122/getting-rgb-value-from-under-mouse-cursor/13061320#13061320)

Comment: Other than your helpful answers, what (if any) simple beginner errors have I made that should be corrected? Any redundancies or incorrect statements that I should change?

Comment: Other then blocking the EDT, which is your main problem, it's typically discouraged to extend from `JFrame` itself, you're locking yourself into a single use-case, `JFrame` has a complex enough structure on it's own and you're not really adding any value. `JPanel` might be a better starting point.  You should also be starting the UI from within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details, this will help prevent any possible issues with thread locks and other issues